# Call a static C# function without its class name in PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Let's say you wrote a totally awesome function in C# and want to use it in your PowerShell script. You can do this like so:

```
$Source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
  public static int AddNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source

[BasicTest]::AddNumbers(4, 3)
# output: 7
```

The question is, how to call this function without `[BasicTest]::` part? Like this:

```
AddNumbers(4, 3)
```

What I tried (and it didn't work)

```
using namespace BasicTest
```

```
Set-Alias -Name AddNumbers -Value [BasicTest]::AddNumber
```

Comment: You could wrap it in a Powershell function with whatever name you want to use, and call the PowerShell function instead - ```function AddNumbers{ param( $First, $Second ) return [BasicTest]::AddNumbers( $First, $Second ) }``` and then call it with ```AddNumbers 4 3```

Comment: @mclayton, thanks, but I'd rather avoid this method. Main reason - calling even a simple powershell function is slow, while calling a c# function is lightning fast. Try doing it in a cycle of, say, 100k iterations and measure the time.

Comment: Have you tried `using static BasicTest` ?

Comment: @AlexanderK. - sure, if raw performance is a concern then it might not be the way to go.

Comment: Then again, if raw performance is an issue, Powershell itself might not be the way to go :-)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, `using static BasicTest` throws a compiler error.

Comment: @mclayton, while that's generally true, sometimes you can use a trick of some sort (like c# code). Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Make it an instance method instead of a static one. Other than that what you're asking doesn't make sense

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I know c# programmers love their classes, but in this case a static function is fine. As for not making sense, try typing all those square brackets and colons a few dozen times, maybe then it will?

Comment: the best you can get in powershell will be to store the type in a variable and then call the static method `$i = [BasicTest]; $i::AddNumbers(4,3)` that's as good as it gets

Comment: Or using `.Invoke` from PSMethod class `$method = [BasicTest]::AddNumbers; $method.Invoke(4, 3)`